# Java: create object that has a type parameter using reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Consider the following:

> ```
> class A<T> {
>     T t 
> }
>
> class B<T> { }
> ```

I have a Parameter, p, that I know is of type A of some unknown generic type t. I can get the generic type parameter of A via the following:

`Type t = ((ParameterizedType)p.getParameterizedType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];`

Now I want to construct a B that has the same generic type as A. How do I do this? I have tried the following:

`B<t> b = new B<>();`

`Class c = (Class) t;
B<c> b = new B<>();`

Both of these fail with error: unknown type for the type I am providing to B.

I have two questions:

1. How do I construct a B here?
2. What type of thing is the type parameter? Because based on above it leads me to believe that it is not a Class or a Type? So what is it?

Comment: Why do you need that? Have you tried a `public B<T> newB(){ return new B<>(); }` inside `A`?

Comment: The type parameters only exist at compile time.  This is called runtime type erasure.  So you can't create a `B<T>` - just a `B`.

Comment: How do you know that `p` is of type `A`? Reflection is only useful if the types are unknown until run-time. If the types are known at compile-time, you shouldn't be using reflection.

Comment: I have some program invariant that p will be of type A. I agree I wouldn't need reflection if I was only interested in A. But I am interested in the generic type of A which I can pull out using reflection at runtime.

Comment: What is this `p` that you “know is of type A”, but get cast to `ParameterizedType`? `A` does not implement `ParameterizedType`, so if `p` is really of type `A`, this code will simply fail with a class cast exception. So besides the fact that you didn’t get the type argument of `A`, what do you think, would be the consequence of writing `B<c> b = new B<>();` instead of `B<Object> b = new B<>();`, given that you don’t know what `c` is? The point of generic code is that it is *generic*, i.e. doesn’t depend on the actual type arguments you use.